# Bison shift/reduce conflict / reduce/reduce conflict warnings

Tags: warnings, bison, shift-reduce-conflict

When I run this bison code in Ubuntu Linux i get these warnings:

```
- shift/reduce conflict [-Wconflicts-sr]
- reduce/reduce conflicts [-Wcolficts-sr]
```

Here's a screenshot for more clarity:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEDy1.png

Edit: reduce/reduce errors are in

```
line 86 : typos_dedomenwn
line 101: typos_synartisis
```

and the shift/reduce error is in:

```
line 129: entoli_if
```

I can't find how to fix them could someone help?

Here's the bison code bellow :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int totalerrors=0;

extern int yylex();
extern FILE *yyin;
extern int lineno; //Arithmos grammis pou kanei parse

//error handling
void yyerror(const char *msg) {
}
//filling the error array
void printError(char y[],int x){
    //param 1: error string
    //param 2: line number
    char temp[15];
    char temp2[5];
    char final[256];
    sprintf(temp2,"%d: ",x);
    strcpy(temp, "In Line ");
    strcat(temp,temp2);
    strcpy(final,"");
    strcat(final,temp);
    strcat(final,y);
    printf("%d) %s\n",totalerrors+1,final);
    totalerrors++;
}
%}
%start start
%token T_sigkritikos_telestis
%token T_typos_dedomenwn
%token T_typos_synartisis
%token T_stathera
%token T_newline
%token T_kefalida_programmatos
%token T_extern
%token T_void
%token T_return
%token T_if
%token T_else
%token T_plus
%token T_minus
%token T_mult
%token T_div
%token T_percentage
%token T_int
%token T_bool
%token T_string
%token T_true
%token T_false
%token T_id
%token T_semic
%token T_comma
%token T_openpar
%token T_closepar
%token T_ampersand
%token T_begin
%token T_end
%token T_excl
%token T_or
%token T_equals
%token T_semileft
%token T_semiright
%%
start: exwterikes_dilwseis T_kefalida_programmatos tmima_orismwn tmima_entolwn;

exwterikes_dilwseis: exwteriko_prwtotypo exwterikes_dilwseis
    | ;

exwteriko_prwtotypo: T_extern prwtotypo_synartisis;

tmima_orismwn: orismos tmima_orismwn
    | ;

orismos: orismos_metavlitwn
    | orismos_synartisis
    | prwtotypo_synartisis;

orismos_metavlitwn: typos_dedomenwn lista_metavlitwn T_semic;

typos_dedomenwn: T_int
    | T_bool
    | T_string;

loop1: T_comma T_id
    | ;

lista_metavlitwn: T_id loop1;

orismos_synartisis: kefalida_synartisis tmima_orismwn tmima_entolwn;

prwtotypo_synartisis: kefalida_synartisis T_semic;

kefalida_synartisis: typos_synartisis T_id T_openpar lista_typikwn_parametrwn T_closepar
    | typos_synartisis T_id T_openpar T_closepar;

typos_synartisis: T_int
    | T_bool
    | T_void;

lista_typikwn_parametrwn: typikes_parametroi loop2;

loop2: T_comma typikes_parametroi
    | ;

typikes_parametroi: typos_dedomenwn T_ampersand T_id;

tmima_entolwn: T_begin loop3 T_end;

loop3: entoli loop3
    | ;

entoli: apli_entoli T_semic
    | domimeni_entoli
    | sintheti_entoli;

sintheti_entoli: T_semileft loop3 T_semiright;

domimeni_entoli: entoli_if;

apli_entoli: anathesi 
    | klisi_sunartisis
    | entoli_return
    | ;

entoli_if: T_if T_openpar geniki_ekfrasi T_closepar entoli else_clause 
    | T_if T_openpar geniki_ekfrasi T_closepar entoli;

else_clause: T_else entoli;

anathesi: T_id T_equals geniki_ekfrasi;

klisi_sunartisis: T_id T_openpar lista_pragmatikwn_parametrwn T_closepar 
    | T_id T_openpar T_closepar;

lista_pragmatikwn_parametrwn: pragmatiki_parametros loop4;

loop4: T_semic pragmatiki_parametros loop4
    | ;

pragmatiki_parametros: geniki_ekfrasi;

entoli_return: T_return geniki_ekfrasi 
    | T_return;

geniki_ekfrasi: genikos_oros loop5;

loop5: T_or T_or genikos_oros loop5
    | ;

genikos_oros: genikos_paragontas loop6;

loop6: T_ampersand T_ampersand loop6 
    | ;

genikos_paragontas: T_excl genikos_protos_paragontas
    | genikos_protos_paragontas;

genikos_protos_paragontas: apli_ekfrasi tmima_sigrisis
    | apli_ekfrasi;

tmima_sigrisis: T_sigkritikos_telestis apli_ekfrasi;



apli_ekfrasi: aplos_oros loop7;

loop7: T_plus aplos_oros loop7
    | T_minus aplos_oros loop7
    | ;

aplos_oros: aplos_paragontas loop8;

loop8: T_mult aplos_paragontas loop8
    | T_div aplos_paragontas loop8
    | T_percentage aplos_paragontas loop8
    | ;

aplos_paragontas: T_plus aplos_prot_oros
    | T_minus aplos_prot_oros
    | aplos_prot_oros;

aplos_prot_oros: T_id
    | stathera
    | klisi_sunartisis
    | T_openpar geniki_ekfrasi T_closepar;

stathera: T_true
    |T_false;

%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    ++argv; --argc;  //agnooume to onoma tou exe
    if (argc==1) {
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0],"r");
        if (fp!=NULL) {
            printf("Reading input from file: %s\n",argv[0]);
            printf("Output:\n\n");
            yyin = fp;
            yyparse();
        } else {
            printf("File doesn't exist\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } else if (argc>1) {
        printf("Only one file allowed for input...\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf ("Parsing from stdin..\n");
        yyparse();
    }
    if (totalerrors==0) {
        printf("All good!\n");
        printf("===================================\n");
        printf("Parsing complete! No errors found!!\n");
    } else {
        printf("===================================\n");
        printf("Total Errors: %d\n",totalerrors);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A. Redundant non-terminals

The **reduce/reduce conflicts** are because you have two non-terminals which exist only to gather together different types:

```
typos_dedomenwn: T_int
    | T_bool
    | T_string;

typos_synartisis: T_int
    | T_bool
    | T_string;
```

Where these non-terminals are used, it is impossible for the parser to know which one applies; it cannot tell until further along in the declaration. However, it doesn't matter. You could just define a single `typos` non-terminal, and use it throughout:

```
typos: T_int
    | T_bool
    | T_string;

orismos_metavlitwn: typos lista_metavlitwn T_semic;
kefalida_synartisis: typos T_id T_openpar lista_typikwn_parametrwn T_closepar
    | typos T_id T_openpar T_closepar;
typikes_parametroi: typos T_ampersand T_id;
```

### B. Dangling else

The **shift/reduce conflict** is the classic problem with "C" style `if` statements. These statements are difficult to describe in a way which is not ambiguous. Consider:

```
if (expr1) if (expr2) statement1; else statement2;
```

We know that the `else` must match the *second* `if`, so the above is equivalent to:

```
if (expr1) { if (expr2) statement1; else statement2; }
```

But the grammar also matches the other possible parse, equivalent to:

```
if (expr1) { if (expr2) statement1; } else statement2;
```

There are three possible solutions to this problem:

1. **Do nothing.** Bison does the right thing here, by design: it always prefers "shift" over "reduce". What that means is that if an `else` could match an open `if` statement, bison will always do that, rather than holding onto the `else` to match some outer `if` statement. There is a pretty good description of this in the Dragon book, amongst other places.

   The problem with this solution is that you still end up with a warning about shift/reduce conflicts, and it is hard to distinguish between "OK" conflicts, and newly-created "not OK" conflicts. Bison provides the `%expect` declaration so you can tell it how many conflicts you expect, which will suppress the warning if the right number are found, but that is still pretty fragile.
2. **Use precedence declarations.** These are described in the [bison manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Precedence.html#Precedence) and their use in solving the dangling else problem is a running example in that chapter. In your case, it would look something like this:

   ```
   %precedence T_then  /* Fake terminal, needed for %prec */
   %precedence T_else
    /* ... */
   %%
    /* ... */

   entoli_if: T_if T_openpar geniki_ekfrasi Tw_closepar entoli T_else entoli
      | T_if T_openpar geniki_ekfrasi T_closepar entoli %prec T_then
   ```

   Here, I have eliminated the unnecessary non-terminal `else_clause` because it hides the `else` token. If you wanted to keep it, for whatever reason, you would need to add a `%prec T_else` to the end of the `entoli_if` production which uses it.

   The `%precedence` declaration is only available from bison 3.0 onwards. If you have an earlier version of bison, you can use the `%nonassoc` declaration instead, but this may hide some other errors.
3. **Fix the grammar**. It is actually possible to make an unambiguous grammar, but it is a bit of work.

   The important point is that in:

   ```
   if (expr) statement1 else statement2
   ```

   `statement1` cannot be an unmatched `if` statement. If `statement1` is an `if` statement, it *must* include an `else` clause; otherwise, the `else` in the outer `if` would match the inner `if`. And that applies recursively to any trailing statements in `statement1`, such as

   ```
   if (e2) statement2; 
     else if (e3) statement3
     else /* must be present */ statement;
   ```

   We can express this by dividing statements into "matching" statements (where all `if` are matched by `else`) and "non-matching" statements: (I haven't tried to preserve the greek non-terminal names here; sorry. You'll have to adapt the idea to your grammar).

   ```
   statement: matching_statement | non_matching_statement ;
   matching_statement: call_statement | assignment_statement | ...
       | matching_if_statement
   non_matching_statement: non_matching_if_statement
       /* might be others, see below */

   if_condition: "if" '(' expression ')' ;

   matching_if_statement:
         if_condition matching_statement "else" matching_statement ;
   non_matching_if_statement:
         if_condition statement
       | if_condition matching_statement "else" non_matching_statement
       ;
   ```

   In C, there are other compound statements which can end with a statement (`while`, `for`). Each of these will also have a "matching" and "non-matching" version, depending on whether the final statement is matching or non-matching:

   ```
   while_condition: "while" '(' expression ')' ;
   matching_while_statement: while_condition matching_statement ;
   non_matching_while_statement: while_condition non_matching_statement ;
   ```

   As far as I can see, this does not apply to your language, but you might want to extend it in the future to include such statements.

### C. Some notes about bison style

1. Bison allows you to use single character tokens as themselves, surrounded by single quotes. So instead of declaring `T_openpar` and then writing verbose rules which use it, you can just write `'('`; you don't even need to declare it. (In your flex -- or other -- scanner, you would just `return '(';` instead of `return T_openpar`, which is why you don't need to declare the token.) This usually makes grammars more readable.
2. Bison also lets you specify a human-readable name for a token. (This feature is not in all `yacc` derivatives, but it is pretty common.), which can also make grammars more readable. For example, you can give names to the `if` and `else` tokens as follows:

   ```
   %token T_if "if"
   %token T_else "else"
   ```

   and then you could use the quoted strings in your grammar rules. (I did that in my last example for the dangling-else problem.) In the flex scanner, you still need to use the token symbols `T_if` and `T_else`.
3. If you have a two-symbol token like `&&`, it is usually better if the scanner recognizes it and returns a single token, instead of the parser recognizing two consecutive `&` tokens. In the second case, the parser will recognize:

   ```
   boolean_expr1 &  & boolean_expr2
   ```

   as though it had been written

   ```
   boolean_expr1 && boolean_expr2
   ```

   although the first one was most likely an error which should be reported.
4. Bison is a bottom-up LALR(1) parser generator. It is not necessary to remove left-recursion. Bottom-up parsers *prefer* left-recursion, and left-recursive grammars are usually more accurate and easier to read. For example, it is better all round to declare:

   ```
   apli_ekfrasi: aplos_oros
       | apli_ekfrasi '+' aplos_oros
       | apli_ekfrasi '-' aplos_oros;
   ```

   than to use LL-style repeated suffixes (`loop7` in your grammar). The left-recursive grammar can be parsed without extending the parser stack, and more accurately represents the syntactic structure of the expression, making parser actions easier to write.

   There are a number of other places in your grammar which you might want to revisit.

   (This advice comes straight from the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Recursion.html): "you should always use left recursion, because it can parse a sequence of any number of elements with bounded stack space.")

Comment: Is there a way to validate the changed yacc file is equivalent to the original one? @rici